# Error while inserting array of document in collection : Unable to parse JSON . Expecting '{', at (1,1)

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb

Dealing with MongoDb. I am inserting array of document & its giving error.

```
[
    { "Company":"Dell",

 "Product":"Laptop"
},

{
    "Company":"Lenovo",

   "Product":"Lap"
}]
```

This is what I am  inserting in document of collection. While saving this document ,  it is giving me error : " Unable to parse JSON . Expecting '{', at (1,1). "

Comment: take a look at this https://github.com/paralect/robomongo/issues/544

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/JSON_bad_parse

Parsing through JSON does not allow trailing commas.  Try deleting the comma that separates the two objects.  Like so:

```
[
    { "Company":"Dell",

 "Product":"Laptop"
}

{
    "Company":"Lenovo",

   "Product":"Lap"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use the single quote like this:

[ '{ "Company":"Dell",

"Product":"Laptop" }',

'{ "Company":"Lenovo",

"Product":"Lap" }']

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have disconnected from localhost. I also had the same issue but I disconnected from localhost and everything went fine.